# How to construct a vector with unique pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, initializer-list, list-initialization

I try to construct a vector with unique_ptr. But I do not find a direct way. The following code does not compiles. The error is:Call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::__1::unique_ptr >':

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
class test1{
public:
    test1(){};
    test1(test1&&)=default;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::unique_ptr<test1> us(new test1());
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<test1>> vec{move(us)};
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This `make_vector` is a function that takes any number of arguments, and perfect-forwards them into a vector.

```
// get the first type in a pack, if it exists:
template<class...Ts>
struct first {};
template<class T, class...Ts>
struct first<T,Ts...>{
  using type=T;
};
template<class...Ts>
using first_t=typename first<Ts...>::type;

// build the return type:
template<class T0, class...Ts>
using vector_T = 
  typename std::conditional<
    std::is_same<T0, void>::value,
    typename std::decay<first_t<Ts...>>::type,
    T0
  >::type;
template<class T0, class...Ts>
using vector_t = std::vector< vector_T<T0, Ts...> >;

// make a vector, non-empty arg case:
template<class T0=void, class...Ts, class R=vector_t<T0, Ts...>>
R make_vector( Ts&&...ts ) {
  R retval;
  retval.reserve(sizeof...(Ts)); // we know how many elements
  // array unpacking trick:
  using discard = int[];
  (void)discard{0,((
    retval.emplace_back( std::forward<Ts>(ts) )
  ),void(),0)...};
  return retval; // NRVO!
}
// the empty overload:
template<class T>
std::vector<T> make_vector() {
  return {};
}
```

use:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<test1>> vec =
  make_vector(
    std::move(u1), std::move(u2)
  );
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/492a7999c4196ca2)

I polished it a bit.  It will deduce the return type if you pass it 1 or more args and you don't pass it a type.  If you pass it a type, it will use that type.  If you fail to pass it a type or any args, it will complain.  (if you forward packs, or are storing it in a particular type, I'd always give it a type).

---

A further step could be done, where we do return type deduction to eliminate the requirement to specify the type even in the empty case.  This may be required in your use case, I don't know, but it matches how you don't need to specify the type of a `{}`, so I thought I'd toss it out there:

```
template<class...Ts>
struct make_vec_later {
  std::tuple<Ts...> args; // could make this `Ts&&...`, but that is scary

   // make this && in C++14
  template<class T, size_t...Is>
  std::vector<T> get(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return make_vector<T>(std::get<Is>(std::move(args))...);
  }

  // make this && in C++14
  template<class T>
  operator std::vector<T>(){
    return std::move(*this).template get<T>( std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{} );
  }
};
template<class...Ts>
make_vec_later<Ts...> v(Ts&&...ts) {
  return {std::tuple<Ts...>(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...)};
}
```

this does rely on a C++14 feature of `index_sequence`, but those are easy to rewrite in C++11 if your compiler doesn't have it yet.  Simply google it on stack overflow, there are a myriad of implementations.

Now the syntax looks like:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<test1>> vec =
  v(std::move(u1));
```

where the list of arguments can be empty.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/749a241ad0fbf308)

Supporting variant allocators is left as an exercise to the user.  Add another type to `make_vector` called `A`, and have it default to `void`.  If it is void, swap it for `std::allocator<T>` for whatever type `T` is chosen for the vector.  In the return type deduction version, do something similar.

Comment: Is there a similar solution for maps?

Comment: @eckhardn you do not want a unique pointer key in map or a set.  Otherwise, sure, you just have to either pass in pairs and change return types, or do something overly complex with varargs.

Comment: I need as key unsigned and as value the unique pointer. I tried to change your code for maps, but did not managed it.

Answer (score 9):

You're calling the [`vector` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) ((7) on the linked page) that takes an `initializer_list<T>` argument. An `initializer_list` [only allows `const` access](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8193102/241631) to its elements, so the `vector` must copy the elements, and this, of course, fails to compile.

The following should work

```
std::unique_ptr<test1> us(new test1());
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<test1>> vec;

vec.push_back(move(us));
// or
vec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<test1>(new test1()));
// or
vec.push_back(std::make_unique<test1>()); // make_unique requires C++14
```

---

You could use the `vector` constructor that takes two iterators, but the solution is still not a one-liner because it requires you to define a temporary array that you can then move from.

```
std::unique_ptr<test1> arr[] = {std::make_unique<test1>()};
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<test1>> vec{std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(arr)),
                                        std::make_move_iterator(std::end(arr))};
```

Comment: In my situation, I can not use the push_back. I need  a constructor because of recursion. Do I understand you right, that there is no possibility to use a constructor?

Comment: or `vec.emplace_back(new test1())`.

Comment: vec.emplace_back also is not possible for my problem

Comment: @0x499602D2 Not exception safe, if `emplace_back` throws, you'll leak.\

Comment: So does your example. Why not a `push_back(make_shared<test1>())`?

Comment: @EckhardN I can't think of another way to construct a `vector` by transferring ownership from an existing `unique_ptr`. Can you post an example showing the problem you're facing? Maybe there's a different workaround

Comment: I am writing a code generator where I need to construct an object without extra code like using push_back. I depend on an constructor.

Comment: @0x499602D2 So does my example what? In the second case the `unique_ptr` construction is guaranteed to be complete prior to `push_back` being called. `push_back(make_shared<test1>())` won't compile, and I didn't mention `push_back(make_unique<test1>())` because the question is tagged C++11, but I'll add that anyway.

Comment: @EckhardN *Why* can you not add an line for a `push_back` call? Unless you add an example, it's hard for me to suggest a solution.

Comment: @Praetorian I am constructing a tree of objects, where I had the idea to do something like: std::vector<std::vector<..>>foo{{{unique_ptr,unique_ptr,..},{unique_ptr,unique_ptr,...}...}}

Comment: @EckhardN Added another option, but it probably doesn't meet your requirements either. Sorry, I don't think what you want to do is possible in that form.

Comment: @PraetorianThank you! Yes, a temporary array is not a possible solution. So I have to find a totally different solution. I will write n-functions with 1 to n parameters, which will construct a return the vector. Not elegant, but the best I think of.

Comment: @EckhardN If you have some sample code, I'm sure we can probably find a solution that doesn't involve using N overloads.