# why auto i = same_const_variable could not deduce "const"?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, type-deduction

```
const int ci = 10;
auto i = ci;  // i will be "int" instead of "const int"
i = 20;
```

I am wondering why auto is designed for this kind of behaviour?

why the type i is "int" instead of "const int" ?

what is the concern here?

I think understand why will help us to remember it

Comment: because value of `ci` is `int` and `auto` deduced `int` for `i`.

Comment: so why auto &i = ci; deduce const int& ?

Comment: Because in order to refer to a const object, a reference must be const.  `auto i = ci;` is making a copy, and copies of const objects have no need to be const.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal "_value of ci_" value is not a proper C++ term; do you mean, the result of conversion to rvalue?

Comment: @camino What did you expect?

Comment: If auto has deduced const, then how would you use auto to remove const from a type? remove_const? Tedious!

Comment: @user1535111 Why would you use auto to remove const from a type?

Comment: @curiousguy Suppose you have a function argument which will be used multiple times, then you may want to declare it as const. At the same time, you want to copy it for some usage, then you need to remove const from the type of the argument.

Comment: Take a look at this blog post here http://aary.logdown.com/posts/258811-powerful-features-in-c-11-and-c-14-type-deducing

Comment: @camino: Because that does _not_ involve an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`auto` mostly follows the same type deduction rules as template argument deduction. The only difference is that `auto` will deduce `std::initializer_list` from a *braced-init-list* in some cases, while template argument deduction doesn't do this.

From N3337, *§7.1.6.4 [dcl.spec.auto]*

> 6   ... The type deduced for the variable `d` is then
>   the deduced `A` determined using the rules of template argument deduction from a function call (14.8.2.1), ...

The behavior you're observing is the same as what template argument deduction would do when deducing types from a function call

*§14.8.2.1 [temp.deduct.call]*

> 2   If `P` is not a reference type:
>       — ...
>       — If `A` is a cv-qualified type, **the top level cv-qualifiers of `A`’s type are ignored for type deduction**.

Thus, in

```
auto i = ci;
```

the top level `const` qualifier is ignored and `i` is deduced as `int`.

When you write

```
auto& i = ci;
```

then `i` is no longer not a reference type and the above rule doesn't apply, so the `const` qualifier is retained.

Comment: so why template is designed for this kind of behaviour ? :)

Comment: @camino You are making a fresh copy. Why should the CV-qualifications of the original affect that of the copy?

Comment: @T.C. Nice double negative :) Thanks for the fix

Comment: @camino "Why template is designed for this kind of behavior?" - that's a separate question. Post it as a separate question. (Though it may be off topic because it's asking a question about what the Standards committee was thinking, and nobody can answer that except the Standards committee.)

Comment: @RaymondChen It isn't offtopic and it's pretty much the same question, and the answer has already been given.

Comment: @curiousguy not really.  Chained derived questions being spewed in comments after the question has already been solved in the answer is a problem.  Why it happens really is that it is based off template type deduction.  Why template type deduction does that is a related, but different question.

Comment: @Yakk No. It is the exactly same question.

Comment: @curiousguy I don't see how it's the same question. But in any case, comments are not the place to debate that. And, as Raymond said, *why template argument deduction does this* is possibly off topic as opinion based, unless we can get someone who was present when that decision was made is able to answer.

Comment: @Praetorian The OP wants to understand why X works this way (not which clause of the std describes this behavior), saying X is defined in term of Y doesn't explain anything. The questions even uses the word "design". "_is possibly off topic as opinion based, unless we can get someone who was present_" but it is *not* "opinion based", it's a trivial observation about normal copy semantic. A copy of a const object need not be const.

Comment: @Praetorian Are you seriously suggesting that we need to be present during the discussion to understand that when calling a template function take an argument by value with a lvalue of type int, lvalue-to-rvalue will be performed?

Comment: @curiousguy You don't need to be present to know that lvalue-to-rvalue will be performed. It's written right there in the language spec. However, you need to have been present to know *why* the rule was written that way.

Comment: @RaymondChen C++ was not created by a committee.

Comment: @curiousguy That'll be quite a surprise to Herb Sutter, who has chaired the C++ standards committee for over a decade.

Comment: @RaymondChen No it will not. Also, templates are older than 10 years.

Comment: @RaymondChen "_However, you need to have been present to know why the rule was written that way._" In C++ the name of an integer variable (even of type `const int`) is an lvalue. It doesn't designate an integer value, it designates an object. You need to convert it to an rvalue to obtain its numerical value. It isn't new or specific to templates or `auto`, it has always been that way.

Comment: @curiousguy There is no conversion to obtain the value. The template is interested only in binding to the object's type. And the type of `ci` is `const int&`. (And you can certainly have lvalue types as template parameters.) Besides, if lvalue-to-rvalue conversion were automatic, then we wouldn't have needed the clause in rule 14.8.2.1 quoted above which explicitly removes cv-qualifiers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87619/discussion-between-curiousguy-and-raymond-chen).

Comment: @Praetorian  "The only difference is that auto will deduce std::initializer_list from a braced-init-list in some cases" Could you please explain that in more detail for me?

Answer (score 5):

`auto` by itself means that you want a new, locally-owned variable with a copy of the given value. `const`-ness is not part of value. An `int` is an `int` whether it's specified using a literal, a named constant, an expression, or a non-`const` variable.

```
auto i = 3,
     j = i,
     k = ci,
     m = 3 + 4; // All these variables are type int.
```

To get a constant of deduced type, you can still use `auto const`. This expresses within the declaration how the variable may be used.

```
const auto i = 3;
```

Since C++14, there is also the `decltype(auto)` specifier which applies `decltype` to the initializer, to make a carbon copy of the given variable. Perhaps that's really what you expected:

```
decltype(auto) i = ci; // i receives type const int.
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28a91215ff98ccf6).

`decltype(auto)` is a bit tricky, though, and it has few use cases aside from its original purpose relating to deciding the return type of function call wrappers. Unless there's a good reason, choose `const auto` or `const int` instead.

Another alternative is to use a *forwarding reference*, spelled `auto &&`. This refers to the variable or value that initializes it, whatever that may be.

```
auto && i = ci; // i receives type const int & and aliases ci.
```

This is less expressive and specific, but reliably declares `i` as an alias to `ci`. The other thing you tried was `auto &`, which is similar but only allows forming a reference to a preexisting variable.

```
auto & i = ci; // i receives type const int & and aliases ci.
```

A reference to a `const int` variable must be of type `const int &`, because otherwise it would permit illegal modification.

Comment: @curiousguy `decltype(x)` is different from `decltype((x))`. It's an abomination *and* it's tricky. However, its behavior is the same as the expectation implied in the question.