# Discrimination When Using auto specifier to deduce the type of a Prvalue in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, auto, type-deduction

I am trying to understand why the C++ standard/compiler discriminates against the behavior of `auto`. The example that I have is as follows:

```
int main()
{
    
    const int i = 34;//top level const on rhs. i is const int
    const auto &p = i;// low level const on rhs. p is const int&
    
    
    auto &g = i;//g is const int& . In this case the compiler is able to deduce that only reference to const can be bound to a const int 
    
    //auto &k = 5;//but in this case the compiler is not able(allowed) to deduce that only a reference to const can be bound to a prvalue 
    
    return 0;
}
```

As seen in the above code example, the compiler is able/allowed to deduce the type of variable `g` since only a reference to const type can be bound to a const type whereas in the next case the compiler is not able to deduce the type of variable `k` even though only a reference to const type can be bound to a const type. Ofcourse a rvalue reference can also be bound to a prvalue or xvalue.

My question is that even though we have a lvalue reference to some `auto` deduced type then why is the C++ standard does not allow the compiler to deduce `k` as `const int&` just as in the case of variable `g`? This seems intuitive enough to me. Maybe there are some problems associated with this which any of you can tell me.

I know that top level const of the initializer are ignored. For example,

```
const int i = 5;
auto k = i; //k is deduced to be int because the top level const of the initializer i is ignored
```

My question is about the implicit addition/deduction of the low level const on the rhs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why auto i = same\_const\_variable could not deduce "const"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32130745/why-auto-i-same-const-variable-could-not-deduce-const)

Comment: No it doesn't because that question is about top level const which i understand. I want to know why for a prvalue a low level const is not added whereas for a const lvalue it is added.

Comment: Please, tell what "low level" and "top level" `const` are. In the question.

Comment: For example if i write `const int i = 5;` then the const appearing on the left hand side is a top level const. On the other hand if i write `const int *k = &i;` then the const appearing in this case on the left hand side is said to be a low level const.

Comment: I don't know this terminology, but I understand the difference. However... how is this related to your question, where you have no pointers in the game?

Comment: Check out my Edit, there i have explained what i am asking. In particular, my question is about the implicit addition/deduction of low level const in the rhs. Also, the example of pointer that i gave in the comment is a reply to your question about "tell what low level and top level" const are.

Comment: I'd be curious to know where this "low/top level" thing goes with a pointer like `int const * * const * const * x;` :D

Answer (score 4):

The reason why

```cpp
auto &k = 5;
```

is not compilable is the same reason for which the following is not compilable

```
template<typename T>
void f(T&) {}

int main() {
    f(5);
}
```

So if the question is *why can't `auto` be deduced as `const int`?* in the first snippet, that question translates to *why can't `T` be deduced as `const int`?* in the second snippet.

Well, *the rules¹* say that the type of the expression that you pass to `f`, in this case `int` because `5` is `int` (and there's no `const` going on here), is ***pattern-matched*** against the type of the parameter, which is `T&`, to determine `T`. So the only possibility is that `T` be `int`, and therefore the parameter's type is `int&`.

But a `int&` parameter can't be passed an *rvalue* such as `5`, and this has nothing to do with type deduction. Indeed, the error that Clang gives for `f(5)` above is

> candidate function [with `T` = `int`] not viable: expects an lvalue for 1st argument

So there's no smart thing as *"can I add a `const` to make this valid?"* going on.

Compare the above with the reason why `const` is deduced here:

```cpp
const int i = 34;
auto &g = i;
```

Well, again, you can map the second statement to `f(i)` with the `f` I defined above. In this case, the expressions (`i`) is of type `const int` (not `int` as the `5`), so when `T&`is pattern-matched against it, `T` is deduced as `const int`.

---

¹ I'm referring to *Item 1* from *Effective Modern C++* by Scott Meyers.