# C++ std::unique_ptr stored inside std::map use of deleted function ill formed

Tags: c++, dictionary, unique-ptr

I have the following code which won't compile and it's Friday and I'm a bit frazzled.

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <map>

template< typename T, typename ...Args >
std::unique_ptr< T > make_unique( Args && ...args )
{
    return std::unique_ptr< T >( new T( std::forward< Args >( args )... ) );
}

struct A
{
};

std::map< std::string, std::unique_ptr< A > > _map = { { "A", make_unique< A >() } }; // <-- ERROR!!
```

The following compiles without a problem

```
int main()
{
    std::pair< std::string, std::unique_ptr< A > > p { "B", make_unique< A >() };
    _map.insert( std::make_pair( "C", make_unique< A >() ) );
}
```

The error I'm getting is (roughly, as removed g++ fluff)

```
use of deleted function 'constexpr std::pair<...>( const st::pair<...> & )
'constexp std::pair<...>::pair( const std::pair<...> & ) is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be illegal.
```

Argghh!!
Just read this in the c++11 standard.

> When an aggregate is initialized by an initializer list, as specified
>   in 8.5.4, the elements of the initializer list are taken as
>   initializers for the members of the aggregate, in increasing subscript
>   or member order. Each member is **copy-initialized** from the
>   corresponding initializer-clause

bummer!!!

Anyone know if it's just plain impossible with initialiser lists?

Comment: I really need this to work with the initialiser lists. The code which compiles was just for example.

Comment: Hmm. Just wondering. Do initialiser_lists require their arguments to be copyable? In which case, the error would make sense as you can't copy a unique_ptr

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193102/initializer-list-and-move-semantics) seems relevant....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do much about it: elements in an initializer list are copied. This will not get along with classes that are move-only.

There's a way to bypass this "defect" but it isn't very nice to read; you decide

```
using map_type  = std::map< std::string, std::unique_ptr< A > >;
using pair_type = map_type::value_type;
pair_type elements[] = { { "A", std::make_unique< A >() }, { "B", std::make_unique< A >() } };

map_type myMap { std::make_move_iterator( begin(elements) ), std::make_move_iterator( end(elements) ) };
```

which will make `myMap` iterate over the range and move the elements within, rather than copying. Method kindly taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468774/can-i-list-initialize-a-vector-of-move-only-type) other question.

Comment: That's a good way of getting around it but it is, like you say, not nice. However, as it solves the problem I have at the moment, you get the gold star :o)