# initializer_list for heavy objects

Tags: c++, initializer-list

I have a (templated) function like this:

```
template<typename T>
void func(std::initializer_list<std::vector<T>> args)
{
    for (const auto &values : inputValues)
    {
        someOperation(values);
    }
}
```

But I'm pretty sure this is not what I want. What I want is a function that can receive an arbitrary number of `std:vector<T>`s avoiding copies (in fact, they should be received as `const` since I am not modifying them inside). Ideally, I would like to be able to pass both rvalues and lvalues, like:

```
std::vector<int> myVec {1, 2, 3};
func({myVec, {4, 5}});
```

The problem that I have with the current declaration is that I *think* (although I have not found any source explicitly confirming or refuting this) that, as it is right now, the initializer list will copy the vectors on creation (I know that they would not get copied when the initialization list itself is copied in any case); is this correct? If that is the case, is:

```
template<typename T>
void func(std::initializer_list<const & std::vector<T>> args)
{
    // ...
}
```

What I am looking for? And would that allow me to use rvalues? I am open to options different than initializer lists (I'm not sure I'd be able to use variadic templates, because this function template is explicitly instantiated and compiled into a library, but if there is an alternative with that it would be interesting to see).

Comment: What is `func` doing?

Comment: It performs a mathematical computation using the vectors in `args`, but it does not modify them.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I've updated the question to make that clearer.

Comment: See also [initializer_list and move semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193102/initializer-list-and-move-semantics)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not want an `initializer_list` because it will force a copy if you attempt to initialize other `vector`s with it. Instead you want forwarding references with a variadic template:

```
template<class... T>
bool func(T&&... vectors);
```

Which you can then `std::forward<T>(vectors)...` as you see fit.

This allows you to opportunistically avoid copies.

For example

```
std::vector<int> a;
std::vector<int> b;
std::vector<int> c;
// initialize a, b, and c

func(std::move(a), std::move(b), std::move(c));
```

If you want to enforce all the vectors are received by const ref, try this:

```
template<class... Vec>
bool func(const Vec&... vectors);

//...
func(a, b, c); // pass all by const ref
```

An `initializer_list` is a bad choice in many scenarios not only because of the copy-on-construct issue, but also because it refers to an array of elements with local scope. The implication here is that if you ever wanted to copy return it, you'd end up with silent undefined behavior (and if you accidentally disable RVO, or the compiler doesn't implement RVO or implements it improperly for `initializer_list`, you're out of luck again)

---

Re your edit:

> I am not actually using the initializer list to initialize anything, I just use it as a lightweight arguments container and, iterating its values and read the values in the vectors (I'll update the question to make that clearer). Would this also cause the creation of copies?

No it wouldn't necessitate any copy creation. There's no problem with using an `initializer_list` that way per se, but that's not its intended use. It's intended use is for a class constructor to have an `initializer_list` constructor. If you're looking for a container you can iterate over, there's no harm in making a vector of references to your other vectors (`std::vector<const std::vector<int>&>`)

Comment: @PasserBy: I guess what I'm saying is that if you want to initialize some object via an initializer_list, then it will copy those items; there's no option to move. You're right, however, that copying the initializer_list itself will not copy the items (and also that you should avoid copy returning an initializer list because of the fact that the items have local scope)

Comment: Thanks, those are some good options and insights in general. However, I am not actually using the initializer list to initialize anything, I just use it as a lightweight arguments container and, iterating its values and read the values in the vectors (I'll update the question to make that clearer). Would this also cause the creation of copies?

Comment: @jdehesa: No it wouldn't necessitate any copy creation. There's no problem with using an `initializer_list` that way per se, but that's not its intended use. It's intended use is for a class constructor to have an initializer_list constructor. If you're looking for a container you can iterate over, there's no harm in making a vector of references to your other vectors (`std::vector<const std::vector<int>&>`)

Comment: Okay, that comment along with the rest of the answer solves my question, I think I'll do as you suggest. Thanks!