# Is it possible to store an object which contains a unique_ptr in a static container?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I'd like to store an object that contains a unique_ptr in a static container:

```
Class A
{
public:
    A() {}
    ~A() {}
private:
    unique_ptr<int> p;
};

static vector<A> vec = { A() };
```

But the code fails to compile, as class A is not copyable due to the unique ptr.
How can I solve this, without having to define a copy constructor in class A that would perform a move operation on the pointer?

Comment: For example by defining a move constructor for `A` which performs the move. `std::vector` can also live with movable-only types.

Comment: @Jodocus: I tried, and got the same compilation error. Seems like for static containers, the compiler doesn't convert the copy operation to a move operation implicitly.

Comment: You could implement a copy constructor, or a move constructor to your class and this could work, Consider something like
`static vector<A> vec = { std::move(A()) };`

Comment: @immortal `A()` is already an rvalue, doing `std::move` on it does not help

Comment: @M.M It won't compile. Initializer lists won't allow the moving of its contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it won't compile as written. When list-initializing (with a `{...}`) a `std::vector`, the constructor called is the one with `std::initializer_list`, and [it doesn't allow move semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193102/initializer-list-and-move-semantics).

There are workarounds, but its kind of ugly

```
static auto vec = []{
    std::vector<A> vec;
    vec.emplace_back();
    return vec;
}();
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/g/y4kUcH)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, by defining the destructor, you will lose the automatically generated move-constructor. So you either have to remove it or define a proper move constructor. Then, you can initialize it as easy as

```
static vector<A> vec(1);
```

Comment: @Passer By I never claimed that this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent objects of type `A` from being copyable, then the only way I see is to use a vector of `shared_ptr<A>`. Not sure if this meets your requirements or your intent, but at least it works:

```
static vector<shared_ptr<A>> vec = { make_shared<A>() };
```