# Brace initialisation of derived types

Tags: c++, c++14, list-initialization

I would like to have a type that is just a list of objects that may be derived off some base class.  That is, the caller gets a list of `Stuff` or `MoreStuff` (which is derived from `Stuff`), and can operate on at least the Stuff parts.

This sounds like `std::vector< std::unique_ptr< Stuff > >` to me. However, I also want to initialise it with the brace initializer, and this is where I'm drawing a blank.

This is more or less what I'm attempting:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

struct Stuff {
    std::string s1;
    std::string s2;
};

using AllStuff = std::vector< std::unique_ptr< Stuff > >;

AllStuff const MyStuff = {
    std::make_unique<Stuff>( Stuff{"1", "one"} )
};

struct MoreStuff : public Stuff {
    std::string s3;
};

AllStuff const AllMoreStuff = {
    std::make_unique<Stuff>( MoreStuff{"2", "two", "too"} )
};
```

Or, rather, something like that. The less typing (for adding more `Stuff` to the vector) the better.

The theory would be that there would be a method that would take a reference to either `AllStuff` or `AllMoreStuff` as the parameter, and be able to use `s1` and `s2` from it.  Other methods would only take `AllMoreStuff` and be able to use `s3` (through an appropriate use of `dynamic_cast<MoreStuff*>(...)`).

However, the theory and reality aren't quite lining up yet, and any help in determining how to brace-initialise a list of derived objects would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `std::initializer_list` with `std::unique_ptr` as `std::unique_ptr` is noncopyable and initialization with `std::initializer_list` implies copying.

You could probably switch to `std::shared_ptr` and add constructors to your structs:

```
struct Stuff {
    Stuff(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
        : s1(s1)
        , s2(s2)
    {}

    std::string s1;
    std::string s2;
};

using AllStuff = std::vector< std::shared_ptr< Stuff > >;

AllStuff const MyStuff = {
    std::make_shared<Stuff>("1", "one")
};

struct MoreStuff : Stuff {
    MoreStuff(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2, const std::string& s3)
        : Stuff(s1, s2)
        , s3(s3)
    {}

    std::string s3;
};

AllStuff const AllMoreStuff = {
    std::make_shared<MoreStuff>("2", "two", "too")
};
```

Answer (score 1):

With C++17 you can write

```
MoreStuff{{"2", "two"}, "too"}
```

because the rules for aggregates have been changed to allow base classes (see [P0017](http://wg21.link/p0017)).

With C++14 and earlier, `MoreStuff` is not an aggregate because of the presence of the base class, aggregate initialization doesn't apply, so you'll have to provide a constructor to do what you want.

However, even if you were to use a C++17 compiler, the rest of your code that initializes the `vector`s wouldn't work. You cannot initialize the `vector` using its `initializer_list` constructor if the contained type is non-copyable, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8193102/241631) for details.