# Construct a map From an initializer_list Supporting Polymorphisim and Inline Construction

Tags: c++, dictionary, polymorphism, shared-ptr, initializer-list

Given this set of toy structs:

```
struct foo {
    virtual void print() { cout << "foo";  }
};

struct bar : foo {
    virtual void print() { cout << "bar"; }
};
```

I would like to create a `map` which:

1. Has values which are polymorphic
2. Has values which are non-const
3. Is constructed via `initalizer_list`
4. Constructs the values within it's `initializer_list`
5. Is not initialized using secondary functions/lambdas/macros to convert the `initializer_list` into a `map`
6. Does not require a separate cleanup function

Thus I can't figure out how to make any of these specializations of `map` work:

1. `map<int, foo*>`
2. `map<int, unique_ptr<foo>>`
3. `map<int, foo&>`
4. `map<int, foo&&>`

The only thing that I have found [which will work is `map<int, shared_ptr<foo>>`](https://ideone.com/R5jqxT). I'm unhappy with this because I don't want to allow shared ownership of the values. But it sounds like this is my only option?

Comment: You can subclass the `std::map` and implement the necessary features.

Comment: @Mohit, no, one should not.

Comment: @SergeyA I'm wandering why one should not?

Comment: @Someprogammer The destructor is not virtual amongst other things

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193102/initializer-list-and-move-semantics I am afraid, `shared_ptr` is your only option.

Comment: @Someprogammer inheriting from standard container is usually not a good idea. Polymorphic inheritance is out of the question (due to non-virtual destructor) and non-polymorphic inheritance, while possible, usually doesn't worth the trouble.

Comment: @SergeyA Changing to `std::shared_ptr` for this reason sounds not good. I'd prefer using `std::unique_ptr` and `emplace`.

Comment: @liliscent you can't move-construct the map from initializer list.

Comment: @SergyA T.T I find this greatly disheartening from the language I love.

Comment: That's true, but it's not too much trouble to add an initialization step, comparing to the cost of `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @JonathanMee if you look at my link, there is a draft proposal from move-only initializer lists (which I haven't read). You can take it upon yourself to introduce it into C++20.

Comment: @liliscent I dunno. OP is asking about initializer list, listing it as a requirement. I prefer to answer asked questions, rather than invent questions which suite my answer.

Comment: @SergeyA It looks like [the proposal](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4166.pdf) has been abandoned :(

Comment: @JonathanMee, I guess, the main reason would be `No prototype yet exists. Practice makes perfect.` Proposals are not considered without prototype implementations.

Comment: Thank you the clarification, I'll dig into that