# Why shouldn't you `std::move(*const_cast<T*>(ele))` the elements of a `std::initializer_list`?

Tags: c++

`std::initializer_list<T>` allocates a temporary array `T[]` whose elements are copied from  with the list-initializer. It's `begin` and `end` methods return `const T*`. This makes it so that you can't move the elements and you perform yet another copy. However, it's trivial to do

```
Vector(std::initializer_list<T> IL) :Size{IL.size()}, :Storage{new T[size]} {
    T* slot = Storage;
    for (auto ele = IL.begin(); ele != IL.end(); ele++, slot++)
        *slot = std::move(*const_cast<T*>(ele));
}
```

I'm sure there's some valid reason why `std::initializer_list<T>::begin` returns a `const T*` and thus you shouldn't do what's shown above but I don't see it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [initializer\_list and move semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193102/initializer-list-and-move-semantics)

Answer (score 4):

The initializer list doesn't just return `T const*`. The array that backs it is declared const too.

> **[dcl.init.list]**
>
> [5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.list#5) An object of type `std​::​initializer_­list<E>` is constructed
>   from an initializer list as if the implementation generated and
>   materialized a prvalue of type “array of `N` const `E`”, where `N` is the
>   number of elements in the initializer list.

This means your trivial example potentially attempts to modify an object that's *declared const*. That results in undefined behavior. In the interest of avoiding UB, we shouldn't do that.