# Why elements of std::initializer_list have to be copied?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, initializer-list

cppreference says:

> The underlying array is a temporary array of type const T[N], in which
>   each element **is copy-initialized** (except that narrowing
>   conversions are invalid) from the corresponding element of the
>   original initializer list. The lifetime of the underlying array is the
>   same as any other temporary object, except that initializing an
>   initializer_list object from the array extends the lifetime of the
>   array exactly like binding a reference to a temporary (with the same
>   exceptions, such as for initializing a non-static class member). The
>   underlying array may be allocated in read-only memory.

What's the reasoning behind this decision? Why is moving not ok?

What about copy-ellision?

```
struct A { A(const A&){ std::cout << "Oh no, a copy!\n"; } };
struct B { B(std::initializer_list<A> il); };

int main()
{
    B b{ A{} };
    return 0;
}
```

My compiler ellides the copy. But are these copies guaranteed to be ellided?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193102/initializer-list-and-move-semantics you get a "Probably the reason" in the accepted answer

Comment: I realized while reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193102/initializer-list-and-move-semantics, that is even worse. Elements cannot be moved out of the initializer_ list, because the underlying array is of type const T[N].

Comment: It really seems that the copy constructor calls are elided. Before C++17, one can suppress this elision with `-fno-elide-constructors` GCC flag. Live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/AF6H1RNWtVfkyoOT.

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understood the following sentence: "Probably the reason for this is so the compiler can elect to make the initializer_list a statically-initialized constant." from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193102/initializer-list-and-move-semantics. Why and when should the compiler do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Copy initialization" in C++ doesn't mean things will necessarily be copied. It's just a formal name for the constraints under which initialization will occur. For instance, when copy initializing, explicit c'tors are not candidates. So the following code [will be ill-formed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bda10d5e8aaff2b9)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

struct A {
    explicit A() = default;
    A(const A&){ std::cout << "Oh no, a copy!\n"; } 
};
struct B { B(std::initializer_list<A> il); };

int main()
{
    B b{ {} };
    return 0;
}
```

The single member in the list needs to be copy-initialized from `{}`, which entails calling the default c'tor. However, since the c'tor is marked explicit, this initialization cannot happen.

Copy elision is certainly possible pre-C++17, and is mandatory in C++17 onward in certain contexts. In your example, under a C++17 compiler, since you provide an initializer that is a prvalue (a pure rvalue, not an object), the initialization rules of C++ mandate that the target is initialized *directly*, without intermediate objects created. Even though the context is called "copy initialization", there are no superfluous objects.