# Workaround for not being able to move from initializer_list?

Tags: c++, c++20, move-semantics, initializer-list, c++23

The convenient `initializer_list` syntax seems to come at a price of not being able to move members of the list, creating unnecessary copies.

```
struct  A
{
    // some members which are dynamic resources...
    A() { cout << "Default Constructor\n"; }
    A(const A& original) { cout << "Copy constructor\n"; }
    A(A&& original) { cout << "Move constructor\n";  }
};
    
int main() {
    vector<A> v1{ A() , A() }; // calls copy
    vector<A> v2;
    v2.push_back(A()); v2.push_back(A()); // calls move
    return 0;
}
```

If I understand correctly, this is because de-referencing the initializer iterators gives `const T`, which will be copied even when move is attempted.

Is there a workaround for this?

Reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/44307741/889742, a solution is proposed which uses variable argument templates, as follows:

```
template<class Array> struct maker;

// a maker which makes a std::vector
template<class T, class A>
struct maker<std::vector<T, A>>
{
  using result_type = std::vector<T, A>;

  template<class...Ts>
  auto operator()(Ts&&...ts) const -> result_type
  {
    result_type result;
    result.reserve(sizeof...(Ts));
    using expand = int[];
    void(expand {
      0,
      (result.push_back(std::forward<Ts>(ts)),0)...
    });

    return result;
  }
};

// a maker which makes std::array
template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct maker<std::array<T, N>>
{
  using result_type = std::array<T, N>;

  template<class...Ts>
  auto operator()(Ts&&...ts) const
  {
    return result_type { std::forward<Ts>(ts)... };
  }

};

//
// delegation function which selects the correct maker
//
template<class Array, class...Ts>
auto make(Ts&&...ts)
{
  auto m = maker<Array>();
  return m(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
}
```

(
aside1: this declares an array , will it be optimized away?
aside2: what is the meaning and purpose of `void` in the expression? it seems unnecessary
)

With new changes in C++20 and C++23, is there now a better workaround for all this?

Comment: "*If I understand correctly, this is because de-referencing the initializer iterators gives `const T`*" - that is because the underlying array that the `initializer_list` holds is a `const T[]` array.  You can't move `const` objects, only copy them.

Comment: N calls to `push_back` seems less than ideal, but the next best alternative seems to be to construct a `std::array<T,N>` and then move from that to the `vector`, which doesn't seem a whole lot better.

Comment: The given solution could be simplified a little bit with fold expressions, but that's C++17.

Comment: `ranges::generate_n`?

Comment: To answer one of your questions, the `void(expand{...});` statement that is part of the `operator()` method appears to be an unnamed function declaration returning `void` and taking an `int[]` parameter. The expression `(result.push_back(std::forward<Ts>(ts)),0)` uses a comma operator to execute the push_back before returning a `0` from the expression.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod Thanks. I had already figured all that out, except for the void part. What advantage is there in evaluating the expression as a parameter to a function declaration ( didn't even know you could do that ) rather than just the expression on its own?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: That’s a cast to `void` of an array prvalue, not a function declaration.

Comment: @DavisHerring It's not the valid syntax for a cast. You might say that direct initialization is functionally a type of cast, but "In case of ambiguity between a variable declaration using the direct-initialization syntax (1) (with round parentheses) and a function declaration, the compiler always chooses function declaration. This disambiguation rule is sometimes counter-intuitive and has been called the most vexing parse." See notes under https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: It’s a [function-style cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) ([expr.type.conv]), which does often perform direct initialization.  There’s no ambiguity here because a function declaration cannot omit the declarator-id ([dcl.decl.general]/5)—and because a *braced-init-list* can syntactically appear in a function parameter only after `=` ([dcl.fct]/3).

Comment: @DavisHerring, thanks for the comment above. What version of the standard are you referencing?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: A very recent draft (thus essentially C++23).

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod `void(expand { 0, (result.push_back(std::forward<Ts>(ts)),0)... });` is big brother of a call statement, An empty statement would be equivalent  to `void(0);`, a non-assigning function call statement would be `void(function(arguments)); ` Here we have `void(type{initializer-list});` which is meant to create statically unfolded loop based on that fold-expression  inside of initializer

Comment: I'm actually more curious why we need that `0,` before fold

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie, "I'm actually more curious why we need that 0, before fold" probably to ensure that the initializer-list is never empty.

Answer (score 6):

If you can wait for C++23, ranges can help:

```
#include <array>
#include <ranges>
auto v= std::array{A(),A()}         //c++17
      | std::views::as_rvalue       //c++23
      | std::ranges::to<std::vector>(); //c++23
```

`array` constructor uses CTAD to deduce type from first input and size from number of inputs. Rest is self explanatory.
Instead of constructor `to_array` can be used if only type must be explicitly specified:

```
#include <array>
#include <ranges>
auto v= std::to_array<A>({A(),A()}) //c++20
      | std::views::as_rvalue       //c++23
      | std::ranges::to<std::vector>(); //c++23
```

The compile time type `<A>` argument is not compulsory and can be deduced, iff all the arguments have the same type.
If the exra culrly braces are annoying, `std::make_array` is under test. It is not shipped under the standard yet, but it will omit the curly braces that `std::to_array` needs.
Another option would be to accept a raw array as function input and use `std::move_iterator`:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
std::vector<T> to_vector(T (&&arr)[N]){
     return std::vector<T>(
            std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(arr)),//c++11
            std::make_move_iterator(std::end(arr)));
};

auto v = to_vector({A(),A()});
```

This one looks like the `std::to_array` version, but it is not part of std library - because arrays are special case.
There are plenty of possible combinations, but almost all rely on copy elision - which started as an optimization option with C++11 and continued as mandatory since C++17.