# braced initialization of std::vector of move-only objects fails

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdinitializerlist, braced-init-list

I can concisely (with braces) initialize 5 out of 6 of the following cases:

|  | of copyable | of move-only |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **array** | YES | YES |
| **std::array** | YES | YES |
| **std::vector** | YES | NO |

The one case that doesn't seem to work is attempting initialization of a std::vector of move-only objects; that fails to compile, with message such as: "error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::unique_ptr'".

Why is this?  And is there an alternative initialization syntax that works for that case?

The following program demonstrates.

```cpp
/*
clang++ -std=c++14 -W -Wall -Werror question.cc -o question
clang++ -std=c++17 -W -Wall -Werror question.cc -o question
clang++ -std=c++20 -W -Wall -Werror question.cc -o question
clang++ -std=c++2b -W -Wall -Werror question.cc -o question
g++ -std=c++14 -W -Wall -Werror question.cc -o question
g++ -std=c++17 -W -Wall -Werror question.cc -o question
g++ -std=c++20 -W -Wall -Werror question.cc -o question
g++ -std=c++2b -W -Wall -Werror question.cc -o question
*/
#include <array>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

int main(int, char **) {
  {
    // I can initialize an array, std::array, or std::vector of
    // copyable objects concisely as follows:
    std::shared_ptr<int> a[] = {std::make_shared<int>(42)};
    std::shared_ptr<int> b[] {std::make_shared<int>(42)};
    std::array<std::shared_ptr<int>, 1> c = {std::make_shared<int>(42)};
    std::array<std::shared_ptr<int>, 1> d {std::make_shared<int>(42)};
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> e = {std::make_shared<int>(42)};
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> f {std::make_shared<int>(42)};
  }
  {
    // And I can also initialize an array or std::array (but not a std::vector)
    // of move-only (non-copyable) objects similarly:
    std::unique_ptr<int> a[] = {std::make_unique<int>(42)};
    std::unique_ptr<int> b[] {std::make_unique<int>(42)};
    std::array<std::unique_ptr<int>, 1> c = {std::make_unique<int>(42)};
    std::array<std::unique_ptr<int>, 1> d {std::make_unique<int>(42)};

    // But if I try to do the same with std::vector of move-only
    // objects, it fails to compile.
    // clang++:
    //   "error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor
    //    of 'std::unique_ptr<int>'"
    // g++ (c++14, c++17):
    //     "error: static assertion failed: result type must be constructible
    //     from input type"
    // g++ (g++20, g++2b):
    //     "error: use of deleted function
    //      ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(
    //      const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&)
    //      [with _Tp = int; _Dp = std::default_delete<int>]’
#if 1  // (hard code to 1 for error, 0 for successful compile)
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> e = {std::make_unique<int>(42)};
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> f {std::make_unique<int>(42)};
#endif
    // The most concise workaround I have found is as follows.
    // (This would not work if I wanted to make the vector const.)
    // Notice that initializer-list initialization does succeed,
    // as long as the initializer list is empty!
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> e_workaround = {};
    e_workaround.push_back(std::make_unique<int>(42));
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> f_workaround {};
    f_workaround.push_back(std::make_unique<int>(42));
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or [`vector v(from_range, views::single(make_unique<int>(42)) | views::as_rvalue);`](https://godbolt.org/z/hG5qjvzev) :)

Comment: Relevant question: [initializer_list and move semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8193102/580083). It seems to be still valid.

Answer (score 7):

The constructor you attempt to call is (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

> ```
> vector( std::initializer_list<T> init, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
> ```

(`constexpr` since C++20)

The argument is a `std::initializer_list<T>`, by value. Your call is no different from:

```
auto u = std::make_unique<int>(42);
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> e = {u};
```

If this would move from `u`, it would be a bad surprise. On the other hand, moving the `std::initializer_list` would be of little use, because its just a lightweight proxy to an array of `T` (copying a `std::initializer_list` does already not copy the elements).

Your code for `std::array` and raw c-arrays works, because it is aggregate initialization. No `std::initializer_list` constructor is involved there.

The workarounds look ok. You can write a function to initialize the vector

```
/*const*/ std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> e = from_ints({42,2,31});
```

This would also work when the vector is `const`.

Comment: But I guess `from_ints` would precisely do what the "most concise workaround" in the question does, right? (I mean, `std::vector<NonCopyable> v{}; v.push_back(NonCopyable{whatever});`.)

Comment: You say "Your call is no different from: `auto u = std::make_unique<int>(42); std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> e = {u};` If this would move from u, it would be a bad surprise."    Are you sure?  I expect your code to non-surprisingly fail to compile, with message something like "not an rvalue".  Whereas my initializer *is* an rvalue `std::make_unique<int>(42)`.  So it seems to me the correct transcription would involve `std::move` to cast your `u` to an rvalue: `... 
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> e = {std::move(u)};`  In which case moving from `u` would not be a surprise at all.

Comment: @DonHatch that was only hypothetical speaking. No matter how you put it, the argument is passed by value and it is a `std::initializer_list<T>` an initializer list of values, nothing is moved when you call that constructor. `std::initializer_list` doesnt need a move because copying it does not copy the elements, but the elements are `T` not `T&&`

Comment: Element of `std::initializer_list` are `const`. and moving `const` lead to copy (unless constructor taking `const Obj&&`).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75796039/workaround-for-not-being-able-to-move-from-initializer-list/75881569#75881569